# Same assembly but internal accessor causes error

Tags: c#, properties, .net-assembly, access-modifiers, accessor

I would like use internal access modifier in properties Length and Width, but it is not possible. It causes error. Then in main method it is not possible to get a value from this properties, when I want use WriteLine method. Question is why? I am  in same assembly, or?

```
namespace AbstractPolygon
{
    abstract internal class Polygon
    {
        public double Length { get; protected set; }
        public double Width { get; protected set; }

        abstract internal double GetArea();
    }

    internal class Rectangle:Polygon
    {
        internal Rectangle(double length,double width)
        {
            Length = length;
            Width = width;           
        }

        override internal double GetArea()
        {
            return Length * Width;
        }
    }

    internal class Square:Polygon
    {

        internal Square(double length)
        {
            Length = length;
        }

        override internal double GetArea()
        {
            return Length * Length;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle objRectangle = new Rectangle(15,5);
            Square objSquare = new Square(97);

            Console.WriteLine("Rectangle area of length:{0} and width:{1} is: {2}",
                objRectangle.Length, objRectangle.Width, objRectangle.GetArea());
            Console.WriteLine("Square area of length:{0} is: {1}", objSquare.Length,
                objSquare.GetArea());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the class is `internal`, their members will be internal too, even if they are declared as `public`, since the class as a whole will not be visible in another assembly.

Comment: ok.but point is that, I cant write:                                          public double Length { INTERNAL get; protected set; }
public double Width { INTERNAL get; protected set; } - these INTERNALS causes error - in the main method eroror writes, that it is not possible to get a value from a properties because of access modifier - it looks like class Polygon and last class Program are in the different assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the compiler error

> The accessibility modifier of the 'AbstractPolygon.Polygon.Length.set' accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer 'AbstractPolygon.Polygon.Length'.

`protected` (applied to the setter) means that this setter would be visible to derived classes, even if these classes were in another assembly, but the `internal` modifier of the property forbids this. Access modifiers on the setter are only allowed to restrict the access, but not to widen it. This is why C# is complaining. Apparently C# does not look at the `internal` modifier of the class when taking this decision.

However, you don't need to make members internal, since the class (together with its members) will not be visible in other assemblies anyway. Make the members public, this is no safety threat.

Comment: Thank you for plenary answer